# How to generate different colours with button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner and want to know how I can generate all different colours with the generate button? What do I add to the second parameter of the button addEventListener?

Also, how do I make it generate colours automatically on refresh instead of no colours?

```js
var getcolors = document.querySelectorAll(".palette").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var n = Math.random();
    n = n * 256;
    n = Math.floor(n);
    var a = Math.random();
    a = a * 256;
    a = Math.floor(a);
    var b = Math.random();
    b = b * 256;
    b = Math.floor(b);
    var color = "rgb(" + n + "," + a + "," + b + ")";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
});

document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function() {});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="generate">generate</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Please create a JS Fiddle and update the question with the link. It would be easier for people to debug your code.

Answer (score 2):

If we add the color-code to a function, lets call it `setColors`, we can call that funcion on page-render, and when the button is pressed like so:

```js
function setColors() {
    // Color code
}

// Run on start
setColors()

// Run on button click
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", setColors);
```

Snippet:

```js
function setColors() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".palette").forEach(function (btn) {
    var n = Math.random();
    n = n * 256;
    n = Math.floor(n);
    var a = Math.random();
    a = a * 256;
    a = Math.floor(a);
    var b = Math.random();
    b = b * 256;
    b = Math.floor(b);
    var color = "rgb(" + n + "," + a + "," + b + ")";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}

// Run on start
setColors()

// Run on button click
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", setColors);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="generate">generate</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the button background color of all buttons with `.palette` with a button (`#generate`) click, You just need to create a function and wrap the color change code in that function.

You need to pass the reference of newly created function as a second parameter in event listener to run always when the user click the button with id `generate`.

```js
function colorButtons() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".palette").forEach(function(btn) {
    var n = Math.random();
    n = n * 256;
    n = Math.floor(n);
    var a = Math.random();
    a = a * 256;
    a = Math.floor(a);
    var b = Math.random();
    b = b * 256;
    b = Math.floor(b);
    var color = "rgb(" + n + "," + a + "," + b + ")";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}

colorButtons(); // To run when the page regresh or first time automatically
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  colorButtons();
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="generate">generate</button>

</div>
```